# unable to access scope value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, scope, angularjs-scope

I have a code like this in html:

```
<div ng-if="item.shareText">
 <textarea></textarea>
  <div>
    <select ng-model="shareOptions">
      <option value="PUBLIC" selected>public</option>
            <option value="FOLLOWERS">followers</option>
            <option value="INDIVIDUAL">individuals</option>
          </select>
          <div ng-if="shareOptions == 'INDIVIDUAL'">
          <div
          isteven-multi-select
          input-model="userFriends"
          output-model="outputUserFriends"
          button-label=" icon fullName"
          tick-property="ticked">
         </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In controller:

```
if($scope.shareOptions == 'INDIVIDUAL' && $scope.outputUserFriends.length == 0){
      $window.alert("Please select your INDIVIDUALS");
      return;
    }
```

Here outputUserFriends is showing the length as undefined. Why?

Comment: have you written any directive? if so please post that too. If not then how do you expect the outputUserFriends to reflect on scope

Comment: customized that directive @nikhil

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement, define outputUserFriends like this

```
$scope.outputUserFriends = ['a', 'b']; (your list goes here)
alert($scope.outputUserFriends.length);
```

you will be able to access length of this array. Adding a working codepen here

Checkout this
[codepen](http://codepen.io/madhur_vyas/pen/VmpqGp)

Comment: thanks for the info.@madhur i have list of friends in outputUserFriends. and it's throwing an error like Invalid array length

Comment: Oh I see, outputUserFriends is an array, let me edit the answer for the same

Answer (score 0):

define

```
    $scope.outputUserFriends = {user:''}
```

then check 
`$scpe.outputUserFriends.user.length`
maybe work

Answer (score -1):

This may be because when your using the `$scope.outputUserFriends.length` the ngModel hasn't bind the value into that object.

This can be fixed just defining `$scope.outputUserFriends.length` as an object.

Comment: it's throwing an error Cannot set property 'length' of undefined

Comment: `$scope.outputUserFriends = {}` this is what i meant xD sorry

Comment: Or since your using `$scope.outputUserFriends` as an string just assing an empty string to it

Comment: @Ajay i guess isteven-multi-select is a directive. Please post code for the directive too.

Comment: @german meza: length is a property of js Array prototype and $scope.outputUserFriends is an Array, not an object. So $scope.outputUserFriends = {} is not gonna help in this case.

Comment: @Ajay What do you mean is it a directive?

Comment: Yes.it is an array and contains list of friends @amir

Comment: already posted that part @nikhil <div
          isteven-multi-select
          input-model="userFriends"
          output-model="outputUserFriends"
          button-label=" icon fullName"
          tick-property="ticked">
         </div>

Comment: @Ajay Then may be you are mistaking somewhere. Is this the all code you have got?

Comment: i posted in that directive @nikhil and it is working in some other place

Comment: @Ajay directive is javascript/angular code, without which this html does not have any meaning. look [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) I am talking about such kind of code which I can not see you have posted.

Comment: https://github.com/isteven/angular-multi-select this is the directive which am using.@nikhil